# Why can't I "string".print()?

Tags: python, ruby

My understanding of the `print()` in both Python and Ruby (and other languages) is that it is a method on a string (or other types).  Because it is so commonly used the syntax:

> print "hi"

works.

So why doesn't `"hi".print()` in Python or `"hi".print` in Ruby work?

Comment: if you gave a string object a print method, why would you stop there, every object in the system should then a have a print method. Printing does strike me as not a particularly string like operation, compared with slicing, searching etc... Print is just a particular form of I/O, and you don't see objects like integers and strings with a write method that takes a file handle as an argument.

Comment: Why has this question gotten so many upvotes when it's effectively "why can't I type random crap and have it run"? When did this become about approaching a language from _complete ignorance_?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: take it easy.  The question is about the logic behind what becomes a method and what becomes a global function, etc.

Comment: That's a far more generous interpretation of this question than I can manage.

Comment: Hey guys, I misunderstood how something worked.  Some nice people corrected me and explained my mistake.  Now I know.  That seems like a good thing.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor considering echristopherson's answer, I don't think this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do something like `"hi".print()`, you are implying that the string object `"hi"` has a method `print`. This is not the case. Instead, `print` is a function that takes a string (or other types) as input.

Comment: This is only true for Python. Ruby doesn't have functions, only methods. In Ruby, `print` is a method of the `IO` protocol, implemented by, for example, `IO#print` and `StringIO#print`. Also, there is a convenience method `Kernel#print`, which basically calls `$>.print`, where `$>` is a global variable denoting the default output IO stream (usually, `$>` points to `STDOUT`, but it doesn't have to). It is this convenience method that allows you to say just `print 'Hi'` instead of `$>.print 'Hi'` or `STDOUT.print 'Hi'`.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby does have a method `Object#display` ([doc here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-display)), which sends a representation of the object to the current output stream, or one specified as an argument.

(I find that it's hard to work with in irb if I use `;` at the end of a line to suppress the printing of the return value; if I do that, `display`'s output isn't shown, even if I flush the stream.)

Comment: Thumbs upping this since I didn't know about `Object#display`, even though I think I dislike its existence since it makes no sense that any given object magically knows how to print itself (because a: how should it look? like self.to_s or self.inspect, etc, and b: how does it know where to print itself to? $stdout or $stderr or some random file or socket or what? What a terrible dependency for every single object to need to know about streams)

Comment: @Joshua Cheek: if you don't specify a stream to output to, it uses the value of the pseudoglobal `$>`, which I didn't even know existed until I looked it up.

Answer (score 2):

Why should it work? String classes rarely have void `print` methods - and you would never need them, because the standard static `print` function can print those strings anyway. It is important to note: `method(someObject)` is **not** necessarily the same as `someObject.method()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's ***not*** a method on a string. Prior to [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html), it was a **statement** (just like `break` or `import`), and you could use both `print "hi"` and `print("hi")`. From Python 3, it was [replaced](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) by a **function**, thus you can no longer use `print "hi"`:

> Print Is A Function
>
> The print statement has been replaced with a
>   print() function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the
>   special syntax of the old print statement (PEP 3105).

Answer (score 2):

What do you propose `str.print` should do?

print to stdout? how about stderr? or a file? or a serial port?

Printing to stdout is really a special case but it's so ubiquitous that sometimes it can be overlooked.

Then we'd have to specify where str should print to every time we create a string?

At the very least we'd have to say

```
"foo".print(sys.stdout)
```

Hopefully that looks awful to you too. It's a confusion of responsibilities

Answer (score 0):

`print` isn't a method on a string in Python (or in Ruby, I believe). It's a statement (in Python 3 it's a global function). Why? For one, not everything you can print is a string. How about `print 2`?

Comment: I am not sure but think that there is no statement or reserved words in Ruby. There is just a method http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-print

Answer (score -1):

In case you are more happy to use a method rather than a statement in Ruby you can use the method display (`"test".display`) to achieve this or define a new method easily like

```
class String
  def print
    puts self
  end
end
```

and use it like this

```
"test".print
```

Comment: Monkey patching objects like this is a generally bad habit to be in, and especially in cases like this where you're creating huge dependencies. I know it won't bite you in this case since print is in Kernel, but that's just an exception (that an entire blog post could be written about).

Comment: everybody has the right to his opinion and i see no dependensies here other then when you use a method it has to be defined somewhere in your code

Comment: It depends on an IO stream and the global variable `$stdout`.