# Is it possible to do functional programming in a language without functions?

Tags: ruby, function, functional-programming

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272856/why-cant-i-string-print#comment16458824_12272872), it was stated that Ruby doesn't have functions, only methods. If Ruby doesn't have functions, is it not possible to do functional programming in it? Or am I confused about the term "function"?

I mean "functional programming" in the sense of functions as first class objects, not as in prohibiting mutable state.

Comment: Sure you can pass functions.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094968/337

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Method vs function is quite a fine distinction.

It's easy to view each particular method implementation as a function; just have it take as an extra parameter the object on which the method was invoked (if your language doesn't pass it explicitly; not terribly familiar with Ruby). That doesn't quite give you virtual method calls (i.e. where the particular implementation called is determined by the object at runtime). But it's also very easy to imagine a virtual method call as calling a function that just inspects its first parameter (`self`, `this`, whatever it's called) and uses it to determine which method implementation to call. With those conventions established, `object.method(param1, param2)` differs from `method(object, param1, param2)` only in a trivial syntactic way.

Personally, I view the above as "the truth", and that object-oriented languages just offer syntactic sugar and optimised execution for this because it's such a core part of writing/executing OO programs. That sort of system is also exactly how you do OO when you have functions but not true classes/methods.

It's also **trivially** easy to implement functions with methods, if you think methods aren't functions. Just have an object with a single method and no attributes! This is also how you do functional programming in languages like Java that insist upon everything being an object and don't let you pass methods/functions as first-class values.

All you **need** to do functional programming is things you can pass around as first-class values, which can be used to execute code determined by the creator of the "thing" (rather than determined by the code that's using the "thing"), on demand by code that has access to the "thing". I can't think of a programming language that *doesn't* have this capability.

Comment: Thanks for the last paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

Blocks and Procs are first-class functions. You can pass them around to methods and functions. That's how Ruby is able to support FP-ish things like map and reduce.

More generally, a method *can* be viewed as a function with extra associated state (its `self`), but methods are rarely passed around in Ruby — though they can be — so in practice they're not as important to FP-ish idioms as blocks and Procs.

Comment: I'm not sure it's accurate to call blocks first-class. You can pass them around, yes, but you can't store them in variables or return them without converting them to Procs first.

Comment: @sepp2k: Hence why I grouped blocks and Procs together. They're essentially different ways of dealing with the same thing for the purposes of this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

A function (or more precisely a procedure, since we are not talking about referential transparency here) is isomorphic to an object with only a single method.

That's how first-class procedures are faked in Java, for example: with so-called *SAM* interfaces (Single Abstract Method). It's also how first-class procedures are "faked" in Ruby: anything which responds to `call` (and maybe `to_proc`) is a first-class procedure. There is a convenience class called `Proc` which provides additional features for "procedures" such as currying, and there is literal syntax (`-> (x, y) { x + y }`) for procedures which creates instances of the `Proc` class, but those two aren't strictly necessary:

```
def (i_am_a_first_class_procedure = Object.new).call(x) p x end

i_am_a_first_class_procedure.(42)
# 42
```

Scala is similar, except the method is called `apply`, not `call`. In Python, it's a "magic" method called `__call__`.

Note: I am ignoring closures here. Closures are procedures with state, and objects of course can have state, too, so there's not a real problem in representing them, but expressing the lexical capture of free variables in terms of an object with instance variables gets rather hairy.

Comment: Nice, did not know `.()` delegated to `call`.

Answer (score -2):

Naturally yes, as long as the language is Turing complete.

Added later:

Actually, Ruby supports several cases of typical functional programming. Matz himself stated something about "providing toys for functional programming kids" when he wass adding #curry method to Proc class in Ruby 1.9 But you can do functional programming with methods as well.

Comment: I haven't downvoted the answer yet, but it isn't a very informative answer.

Comment: Have you ever heard about Occam razor?

Comment: Yes. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: This "Anything you can do in one language, you can do in any other Turing-complete language" meme needs to die. The true version of that statement is "All Turing-complete languages are capable of universal computation" — but that's a much more limited claim! Specific programming techniques are language-specific. Case in point: Whitespace is Turing-complete, but you cannot do functional programming in Whitespace, as it does not have functions.

Comment: Non-mathematicians will surely agree with your statement.